# How to extract data in laravel controller from object array in HTTP request passed via ajax

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel, httprequest

i am developing a POS system in laravel 5.2 .From my sales page i am sending an array which contains 1 bill-info object and 1 product-list object array.My controller is receiving the data correctly,but i cant figure out how to extract them in my controller.I have gone through laravel documentation and php.

i have tried.

```
$data = $request->all();
$billinfo = $data[0]->total;
$productlist=$data[1];
```

i have also tried

```
$billinfo = $data[0]->object->total;
```

i have also tried

```
$billinfo = $data[0]->object[0]->total;
```

i have also tried

```
$billinfo = $data[0]->bill->total;
```

if i send the request again to the view like this:

```
$data = $request->all();
return json_encode($data);
```

And then print the response in consol .The consol gives following output:

```
Object {id: Array[2]}
>id:
>Array[2]
  0:Object
    card_number:"0"
    customer_id:"0"
    date:"06/18/2016"
    discount:"0"
    grandtotal:"563.5"
    payment_method:"cash"
    seller_id:""
    tax:"15"
    total:"490"
    __proto__:Object
  1:Array[2]
    0:Object
      stock_id:"5"
      subtotal:"244"
      unit:"2"
      unit_price:"122"
      __proto__:Object
    1:Object
      stock_id:"4"
      subtotal:"246"
      unit:"2"
      unit_price:"123"
```

My ajax sending function is

```
function ajaxsave(obj)
  {  
    var token=$('input[name=_token]').val();
    var baseUrl=document.getElementById("baseUrl").value;
    var url=baseUrl+"/sales/savecart";
    var id=obj;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
      url:url,
      data: {id:id},
      datatype:'json',
      success: function(data) {

                var returndata =JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(returndata);
}
  });



  }
```

I am trying to learn laravel. this is my first project. Please Help !!!

**I think this is the out put of Network XHR if i return var_dump($request->all())**

```
 array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(9) {
      ["customer_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["seller_id"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "06/18/2016"
      ["payment_method"]=>
      string(4) "cash"
      ["card_number"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["total"]=>
      string(3) "244"
      ["discount"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["tax"]=>
      string(2) "15"
      ["grandtotal"]=>
      string(5) "280.6"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["stock_id"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["unit"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["unit_price"]=>
        string(3) "122"
        ["subtotal"]=>
        string(3) "244"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you edit your post and provide the result of a `var_dump($request->all());` placed at the beggining of your fonction please ?

Comment: And also try `$billinfo = $data->id[0]->total;`

Comment: where to put var_dump($request->all());?? in ajax function or controller function.. sry for the dumb que as i am still learning the rope.. :P

Comment: $billinfo = $data->id[0]->total; dnt work

Comment: Put the var_dump in `savecart` method please

Comment: var_dump($request->all());
return json_encode(var_dump($request->all()));

Comment: the above code gives internal server error in consol

Comment: Your AJAX sends data to a PHP script (which url is "base_url/sales/savecart"). In this script (I suppose named `public function savecart($request)` or nearly similar), you have to begin by var_dump the data you receive, doing the `var_dump($request->all());`. Then you can look the result not in your console but in the "Network - XHR" part of "Developer Tool".

Comment: i have added the output in my que now. see my edit.

Comment: OK so it will be $data["id"][0]["grandtotal"] then =]

Answer (score 0):

Ahdaf, to Julqas point need to see the data dump before you send it i.e. how is your JSON data formatted. That said, I suspect your problem a JSON formatting issue i.e. you are probably sending an array to Laravel e.g. you are sending `var billinfo = ["id", [... data]];` which Laravel will assume is raw data.

You can extract it via PHP GET, etc. which will work fine, but if you are expecting Laravel magic then you need to ensure you are sending Laravel JSON e.g. `var billing = {id: 1, record: {id:1, name: 'bob'};` i.e. JSON. Laravel will decode this fine and $request->all() will work fine. Also if you need to send an array of JS data then var billingInfo = {id:1, arrayOfData: [...]}

P.S. Laravel will return a JSON object if it gets a AJAX request so console.log(...) will show JSON but that doesn't mean you are sending it properly formatted JSON.

EXAMPLE OF WORKING FORMAT

```
var billingInfo = {id: 1, email: "person@msn.com", name: "Bob", card: "4448"}
```

Comment: i got the data like: $data = $request->all();$cus_id = $data["id"][0]["customer_id"];$sell_id = $data["id"][0]["seller_id"];$date = $data["id"][0]["date"];   but now i am thinking how to validate them . laravel documentation does not consist of good ajax validation. and my data format is little complex